# Why it is continuously re-fetching graphQL on every second?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, strapi

Filtering data with current date-time using @apollo/react-hooks useQuery() on strapi server with graphQL for my NextJs front application. **myComponent** is rendered after _app.js as children component

**myComponent.js**

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { MY_QUERY } from "../apollo/queries/home/home";

export default () => {

  let currentDateTime = new Date(Date.now());
  let currentIsoDateTime = currentDateTime.toISOString();
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      currentIsoDateTime: currentIsoDateTime
    }
  });

  return <>{data}</>
}
```

Query

```
export const MY_QUERY = gql`
{
  query($currentIsoDateTime: DateTime){
    events(where:{DateTime_gt:$currentIsoDateTime}){
      id
      Title
      DateTime
    }
  }
}`;
```

`currentDateTime` changing time by time and go for fetching a data from graphQL and its goes to infinite

Answer (score 0):

After the data is loaded, apollo will update the `loading` state, which will re-render your component. Now because the Date is created inside render method, it will create a different time on each render.

This makes the variables to your GraphQL API changed, and apollo will refetch the API call with the new variables.

You can check the Network tab in dev console and see that each query is called with a different `currentISODateTime` value

To avoid this, you can re-use the initial date time by initialize it as a state. e.g

```js
const [currentDateTime] = React.useState(() => new Date(Date.now()));
```

Comment: Which you have explained is perfect but It's still lead me to same problem also after initialize `currentDateTime` as a state. Is there any another way to fix it?

Comment: Can you try console.log `currentIsoDateTime` and see if the value change after each render?

Comment: If `currentIsoDateTime` is not applied as variable in query it's printed for max 2 times

Comment: If it's render 2 times then it's correct behaviour: 1 initial load & 1 after data is fetched. But that's if you don't use `currentIsoDateTime`.


Is the 2 printed values the same or different?

Comment: Both printed values are same

Comment: it should be ;) 2nd rerender caused by arriving `data`

Comment: @xadm but isn't fix my problem

Comment: this is not react (hooks) problem - next has some requirements making it incompatible or at least harder

Comment: Yes, I also think, you any idea how could I make is simpler or any other way to do same @xadm

Comment: Could be a [bug on apollo side](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3644). May be you could try use the Query component instead of hooks.

Comment: also tried Query component of react-apollo but not worked :(

Comment: try gatsby and `useStaticQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Query consumes `currentIsoDateTime` then this is a variable to be defined in state:

```
const [currentIsoDateTime] = React.useState(() => new Date(Date.now()).toISOString() );
```